# Error in readRDS(x) : error reading from connection

Tags: r, rtweet

I'm using `rtweet` package with the following commands:

```
library(rtweet)
hrc <- search_tweets(q = "hillaryclinton", n = 100)
Error in readRDS(x) : error reading from connection
```

> Error in readRDS(x) : error reading from connection

Wondering how to solve the issue. Thanks

My session Info is

```
sessionInfo()
R version 3.6.1 (2019-07-05)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS

Matrix products: default
BLAS:   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/atlas/libblas.so.3.10.3
LAPACK: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/atlas/liblapack.so.3.10.3

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C              
 [3] LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8    
 [5] LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                 
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C            
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] rtweet_0.6.9

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] httr_1.4.1     compiler_3.6.1 magrittr_1.5   R6_2.4.0       tools_3.6.1   
[6] Rcpp_1.0.2     jsonlite_1.6
```